# How can I copy files in Python while keeping their directory structure?

Tags: python, copy, directory, file-copying

I have a list of directories which have many sub-directories.

e.x. C:\home\test\myfiles\myfile.txt

I want to copy this to my `X:` drive. How do I copy `myfile.txt` if the `X:` drive only contains `X:\\home`?

I thought `shutil` would create necessary directories when copying files but I was wrong and I am not sure what to use.

Worded another way...

I want to copy `C:\\home\\test\\myfiles\\myfile.txt` to `X:\\home\\test\\myfiles\\myfile.txt` but `X:\\home\\test\\myfiles` does not exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `os.makedirs` along side `shutil.copytree`.

Comment: Just shutil.copytree should be enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: @IamChuckB -- No.  The user wants the absolute path on drive X to be the same as the absolute path on drive C.  So, if I want to copy directory `C:/this/is/a/directory` using `shutil`, I need to make sure that `X:/this/is/a` exists (which is where `os.makedirs` comes in).

Comment: shutil.copytree will error out if the folder in question already exists afaik? I've only used it once and I don't have access to what I wrote but I'm pretty sure that copytree does the setting up of the directory structure for you

Comment: @IamChuckB -- `os.makedirs` isn't to create the directory that is copied.  `os.makedirs` is to create the intermediate directories up to the one that is to be copied.

Comment: You were right about needed os.makedirs. I posted my solution.

Comment: Oh I see, he just wanted the one file and to maintain the structure of directories. If he wanted to completely duplicate everything  under /home, shutil.copytree on /home would have created the appropriate subdirectories as it went - I misunderstood the question being asked:)

Comment: I thought OP wanted to maintain the structure of the directories *and* to copy the entire subdirectory structure.  But that's OK :).  I'm glad OP figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

So here's what I ended up doing. mgilson was right I needed to use makedirs, however I didn't need copy tree.

```
for filepath in myfilelist:
    try:
        with open(filepath) as f: pass
    except IOError as e:
        splitlocaldir = filepath.split(os.sep)
        splitlocaldir.remove(splitlocaldir[-1:][0])
        localdir = ""
        for item in splitlocaldir:
            localdir += item + os.sep
        if not os.path.exists(localdir):
            os.makedirs(localdir)
        shutil.copyfile(sourcefile, filepath)
```

This separates the directory into a list so I can pull off the filename, turning the path into a directory.

Then I stitch it back together and check to see if the directory exists.

If not I create the directory using os.makedirs.

Then I can use my original full path and copy the file in now that the directory structure exists.

Comment: a few commments.  `splitlocaldir = filepath.split(os.sep)` can be `os.path.split(filepath)`.  `splitlocaldir.remove(splitlocaldir[-1:][0])` is confusing as all getout.  Instead, just use `splitlocaldir = splitlocaldir[:-1]` (if I read that correctly).  You can build `localdir` by `os.path.join(splitlocaldir)` too.  Of course, you could probably avoid all these by just doing `localdir = os.path.dirname(filepath)`